# Download image from silverlight webpart in sharepoint2010

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010

I want to download a image from any URL through silverlight webpart in Sharepoint 2010.
I am able to download image from the same site, but not from other ones (within the same server itself).

I am using WebClient class and opening the image file asynchronously.

Please suggest some ways to achieve this.

Comment: When you say you're unable to download images from other sites, what error message or other result do you get? How are you constructing the URL to request the image - some sample code or other examples would really help me to understand your question better.

Comment: I have the URL string in hand already and I am creating a URI object using the URL string. The code is webclient client = new WebClient(); client.OpenReadCompleted += DownloadCompleted; client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri imageURL,UriKind.Absolute)); function downloadcompleted(object sender, event e){            e.results//throws an error if URL is from another site but opens if it is from the same site}